# Mutt asks "Enter keyID", does not accept any IDs

Tags: mutt, pgp, openpgp

I am trying to use Mutt with GPG to encrypt emails. Whenever I try to encrypt, I am asked to "Enter keyID for user@domain". No matter what I enter, it asks me to enter the value.

I definitely have the key in my keystore. I have entered the full key ID, the 32-bit ID, prefixed it with `0x`, added the email, etc, but nothing works. I can also confirm that I definitely have relevant keys in my local store. I do not see an error message.

My `~/.muttrc` at this point just has the standard `gpg.rc` that comes with Ubuntu. Am I doing something wrong? Or is this a bug in Mutt?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your mutt configuration, please? Be careful and doublecheck there aren't any passwords.

Comment: Configuration below - I can't get it formatted properly for stack overflow.

`set from = <redacted>`

`set imap_user=<redacted>`

`set imap_pass=<redacted>`

`set spoolfile=imaps://<redacted>`

`set folder=imaps://<redacted>/INBOX`

`set my_user=user@domain.com`

`set smtp_pass=<redacted>`

`set smtp_url=smtp://<redacted>:587`

`set record=imaps://<redacted>/Sent`

`source colors.muttrc`

`source ~/.gpg.rc`

`set pgp_default_key="0xF8DAC0DE"`

`set pgp_sign_as="0xF8DAC0DE`